# write string in line 4 of text file

Tags: python, file

I need to write a constant string in many files at line 4.
my text file such as :

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "tr_en_itani" (
  "id" INTEGER  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "sura" smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  "aya" smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  "aya_text" text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I need to change line 4th.
How I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is reading your file as a list of lines, this way:

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
```

now, data is a list with each one of your lines, i.e.

```
print(data[0])
```

will print "PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;",

```
print(data[1])
```

will print "BEGIN TRANSACTION;", and so on.

At this point, you can edit the fourth line this way:

```
data[3] = "Your new text"
```

And then, write back the file:

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines( data )
```